# Rails 4 Polymorphic Image uploads with Paperclip not working for all models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, polymorphic-associations, strong-parameters

Rails newbie here...and SO first-timer....

After a couple tutorials I decided to try and build an event management system. Nothing like ambition, right? Events, Artists and Companies all should be able to upload a single image using Paperclip and nested forms. I've made a polymorphic Picture class and it works great for uploading/editing a picture for the Artist, but when I try to set it up for the Event, using the exact same code, I get an "Unpermitted parameter: picture_attributes" error...and nothing saves to the db.

I've been searching/reading for answers for the last 3 days and I'm totally stuck so I thought I'd throw my code up here and see if anyone can spot what I might be missing and help me figure out how to get this to work.

Here's the actual error code from my last attempt to upload an image to an event:

```
Started PATCH "/events/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-19 11:00:37 -0800
Processing by EventsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"AVkztH4s+t2oq/vjXloZeWxOW3pyD8sEorE3crMZr4Q=",
 "event"=>{"title"=>"Image Upload Test", "description"=>"Will this save to the db?",
 "picture_attributes"=>{
   "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe7e9f6a3c8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/kg/_bhw0x954nq1vdxsr4bwktvc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20141219-868-c377uk>, 
   @original_filename="RED_Tails_1.jpg", 
   @content_type="image/jpeg", 
   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; 
    name=\"event[picture_attributes][image]\"; 
    filename=\"RED_Tails_1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, 
    "company_id"=>"1", 
    "venue_id"=>"1", 
    "production_artists_attributes"=>{
     "0"=>{"artist_id"=>"1", 
        "role"=>"German Commander", 
        "_destroy"=>"false", 
        "artist_type_id"=>"1", "id"=>"20"}}}, "button"=>"", "id"=>"12"}
Event Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events"  WHERE "events"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
Unpermitted parameters: picture_attributes
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
ProductionArtist Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "production_artists".* FROM "production_artists"  WHERE
"production_artists"."event_id" = $1 AND "production_artists"."id" IN (20)  [["event_id", 12]]
SQL (1.3ms)  UPDATE "events" SET "company_id" = $1, "description" = $2, "title" = $3, "updated_at" = $4, "venue_id" = $5 WHERE "events"."id" = 12  [["company_id", 1], ["description", "Will this save to the db?"], ["title", "Image Upload Test"], ["updated_at", "2014-12-19 19:00:37.057793"], ["venue_id", 1]]
SQL (1.3ms)  UPDATE "production_artists" SET "artist_id" = $1, "role" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "production_artists"."id" = 20  [["artist_id", 1], ["role", "German Commander"], ["updated_at", "2014-12-19 19:00:37.065119"]]
(90.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/events/12
Completed 302 Found in 114ms (ActiveRecord: 93.3ms)
```

Here are my models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :picture, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :picture
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_one :picture, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :picture
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :small => "180x180#", :thumb => "60x60#" }, 
                        path: ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
                        url: "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
  validates_attachment  :image, :presence => true,
                    :content_type => { :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png) },
                    :size => { :in => 0..1.megabytes }
end
```

Here are my controllers:

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_artist, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
 @artists = Artist.all
end

def show
end

def new
 @artist = Artist.new
 @artist.build_picture
end

def edit
end

def create
 @artist = Artist.new(artist_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @artist.save
    format.html { redirect_to @artist, notice: 'Artist was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @artist }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @artist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

def update
 respond_to do |format|
  if @artist.update(artist_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @artist, notice: 'Artist was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @artist }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @artist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

private
 def set_artist
  @artist = Artist.find(params[:id])
 end

 def artist_params
  params.require(:artist).permit(:first_name, :last_name,
    picture_attributes: [:image])
 end
end


class EventsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
 @events = Event.all
end

def show
end

def new
 @event = Event.new
 @event.build_venue
 @venue = @event.build_venue
 @event.build_picture

end

def edit  
end

def create
 @event = Event.new(event_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @event.save
    format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @event.update(event_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @event }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

def destroy
 @event.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to events_url, notice: 'Event was successfully destroyed.' }
   format.json { head :no_content }
 end
end

private
 def set_event
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
 end

 def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description, :image_url, :company_id, :venue_id,
    production_artists_attributes: [ :id, :event_id, :artist_id, :artist_type_id, :role, :_destroy,
      venues_attributes: [ :id, :name,
        picture_attributes: [:image]]] )
 end
end
```

Here's my views:

```
The Events form:
<%= form_for @event, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
<fieldset id="event-meta">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">     
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 8, class: "form-control" %>
    <br />
  </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
<p>Upload Picture</p>
  <%= f.fields_for :picture do |image_upload| %> 
    <%= image_upload.file_field :image, class: "form-control"  %>
  <% end %>
</div>
....

The Artist form:
<%= form_for @artist, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
<div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :first_name %>
   <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control"  %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :last_name %>
   <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control"  %>
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
<p>Upload Picture</p>
  <%= f.fields_for :picture do |image_upload| %> 
    <%= image_upload.file_field :image, class: "form-control"  %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

So...to me it looks like everything SHOULD work...but it doesn't. I'm probably missing something simple and hope someone out there can point it out for me.

FWIW...Last night while searching for answers I had a thought that it might be better to create a polymorphic Profile model and attach all images to those with a has_one relationship but even if that's the case...I'd really like some help figuring out why I can't get this to work now so I can learn what to look for going forward. I'm completely baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After weeks of banging my head against a wall...I solved it...but I feel like an idiot. I'm leaving it here for anyone else who runs across this problem.

It turns out I didn't quite understand the syntax to nest strong-params. By closing the nested attributes for production artists and venues before the pictures, I was able to get it working. I also got it working for the company model.

So I changed this:

```
def event_params
 params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description, :image_url, :company_id, :venue_id,
  production_artists_attributes: [ :id, :event_id, :artist_id, :artist_type_id, :role, :_destroy,
  venues_attributes: [ :id, :name,
    picture_attributes: [:image]]] )
end
```

to this:

```
def event_params
 params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description, :image_url, :company_id, :venue_id,
  production_artists_attributes: [:id, :event_id, :artist_id, :artist_type_id, :role, :_destroy],
   venues_attributes: [:id, :name],
    picture_attributes: [:image])
end
```

and everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the `event_params` method to this:

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description, :image_url, :company_id, :venue_id,
  production_artists_attributes: [ :id, :event_id, :artist_id, :artist_type_id, :role,    :_destroy,
   venues_attributes: [ :id, :name,
    imageable_attributes: [:image]]] )
end
```

The thing in here is that you set the `as` option for the `has_one` relation to be `imageable`, and probably you will have to do something similar for the view in the fields for and on the model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :imageable

<%= f.fields_for :imageable do |image_upload| %> 
  <%= image_upload.file_field :image, class: "form-control"  %>
<% end %>
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried this. Now I'm getting an "Unpermitted parameters: imageable" error message and again nothing sees to the db.

Comment: Did you add the correct name for the imageable_attributes on the `event_params` method?

Comment: Yeah I did make that change. I'm really at a loss.

Comment: I did restart the server, but it still doesn't work. I'm just learning how to use the console so I haven't really done much with it, no.